# What is the regularity of the map $G:H_0^1\to H_0^{-1}$ where $G$ is Gaussian free field?

Tags: pr.probability

Gaussian free field is a random field indexed by $H_0^1(D)$ where $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. It takes values in $H_0^{-1}(D)$. I am curious, what is the regularity of the map $G:H_0^1(D)\to H_0^{-1}(D)$ where $G$ is Gaussian free field? Is it continuous? Is it better?

Comment: I have noted in my mo post: questions/374533/ that the zero trace subspace,when D is bounded,is Nuclear.Thus your identification is compact

Comment: @user251920 I am not sure what exactly you have in mind. The GFF is a random distribution which I can view either as a map $H_0^1 \to L^2(\Omega)$ (test function to random variables) or as a map $\Omega \to H_0^{-1}$ (distribution-valued random variable). In the first case, the map is linear continuous, in the second case it is just measurable.

Comment: @MartinHairer I am interested in something like the case of Brownian motion, where Brownian motion is a Gaussian measure on the space $C([0,T],\mathbb R^n)$. I am trying to realize GFF as a Gaussian measure on $F(H_0^1,H_0^{-1})$ for some space of functions $F$.

Comment: @user251920 The GFF is a Gaussian measure on $C^\alpha(D,\mathbb{R})$ for every $\alpha < 1-d/2$ (which is negative when $d \ge 2$). The special case $d=1$ is indeed Brownian motion.

Comment: @MartinHairer Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: @MartinHairer Do you have a reference for this fact? Again, I appreciate your response.

Comment: On the point set of Martin Hairer,by the reproducing convolution formula and Chebyshev  inequality,there exists a sequence in the zero trace which converges point-wise as well as in L^2 by density

Comment: @NagarajIyengar Sheffield in his intro to GFF goes over the regularity ("Gaussian free fields for mathematicians"). It simply follows from the formula for GFF $h(x)=\sum a_k\phi_k$ where $\phi_k:=e_{k}/\lambda_{k}^{1/2}$ and $(e_{k},\lambda_{k})$ are the eigenpairs with respect to the L2 norm and wanting those to converge  in $H^{-\epsilon}$ for each small $\epsilon>0$ i.e. $\sum <h,e_{n}>\lambda_{n}^{-\epsilon}<\infty$. For $d=2$ we have $\lambda_{n}\approx n$, but for more general dimensions, Weyl's law gives different asymptotics $\lambda_{n}\approx n^{2/d}$.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you; I'm curious why your argument does not take advantage of the bounded case with zero and nonzero trace property, whereas $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) 
 = W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^n), p > 1$. Note that $u \in H^1_0$ is 'recovered' in both the bounded and unbounded cases, where in the latter, use of Bochner-Minlos theorem is 'legitimized' and the kernel defines nuclearity in any event.